# NVARCHAR or INT Primary Key with UNIQUE constraint

Tags: database, database-design

I have alphanumeric data with a max length of 20 characters. I'm going to store this data in a column with type `NVARCHAR(20)`.

These data are CODES and must be unique, so I decided to make it a primary key column.

But, asking [another question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/138440/is-one-to-one-relationship-requiered), someone has "suggested" me to use an `INT` column as primary key.

What do you think? An `INT` primary key and add a column with an `UNIQUE` constraint or my current design?

I think I'm adding a new column that I'm not going to use, because I need the `NVARCHAR(20)` column to search, and avoid duplicates. In other words, 99% of my where clause will have that `NVARCHAR` column.

Answer (score 1):

I am a strong fan of numeric, synthetic primary keys.  Something like the key you want can be declared `unique` and be an attribute of key.

Here are some reasons:

- Numeric keys occupy 4 or 8 bytes and are of fixed length.  This is more efficient for building indexes.
- Numeric keys are often shorter than string keys.  This saves space for foreign key references.
- Synthetic keys are usually inserted using auto-incrementing columns.  This let's you know the insert order. Note:  In some applications, knowing the order may be a drawback, but those are unusual.
- If the value of the unique string changes, you only have to change the value in one place -- rather than in every table with a foreign key reference.  And, if you leave out a foreign key reference, then the database integrity is at risk.
- If a row is identified by multiple keys, then a single numeric key is more efficient.
- A synthetic key can help in maintaining security.

These are just guidelines -- your question is why synthetic numeric keys are a good idea.  There are alternative issues.  For instance, if space usage is a really big concern, for instance, then the additional space for a numeric key plus a unique index may overrule other concerns.

Comment: I don't know which advantages I will have adding an INT primary key here if I'm not going to use it. All my operations will work with that `NVARCHAR(20)` column.

Comment: Hi , You can insert to the INT column the hash value of the sring input ( in oracle you can use ORA_HASH  function for that - insert into table values (ORA_HASH('somt string) )  ) when you need to query based on it you can do somting like this   "where myIntColumn = ORA_HASH('INPUT STRING)

Comment: @VansFannel . . . Storing an integer is more efficient, both for index lookups and for foreign key references.

Comment: @GordonLinoff And, what about unique constraint? Is it efficient? Because I need to search for that column in the table.

Comment: @VansFannel . . . Adding a unique constraint on a string column is reasonable.

Comment: @GordonLinoff My apologies, but I don't understand why I have to add an `INT` column if on the 99% of my where clause I will use that `NVARCHAR`column.